# Unified Threat Management

Tags: firewall, router, utm

This might be a simple question:

On what layers of the OSI model does Unified Threat Management work?
And what devices do you recommend for using this?

Thanks,
Dempsey

Comment: Dempsey, note that product recommendations are off-topic here, so none can be given. As for the rest, you might want to be more specific to get a *technical* answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Unified Threat Management" is an IDC buzzword and not a technical term with a concise definition. The layers it works on are whatever layers the respective vendor's marketing decided it would work on - without even knowing what "ISO layers" are, that is.

For more buzzwords and a thorough marketing enema check out the [Wikipedia article on UTMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_threat_management).